# PHP replace multiple value using str_replace?

Tags: php

I need to replace multiple value using str_replace.

This is my PHP code fore replace.

```
$date = str_replace(
       array('y', 'm', 'd', 'h', 'i', 's'),
       array('Year', 'Month', 'Days', 'Hours', 'Munites', 'Seconds'),
       $key
    );
```

When i pass `m` in `$key` it return output like.

```
MontHours
```

When i pass `h` in `$key` it return output.

```
HourSeconds
```

it return this value i want the `Month` only.

Comment: show us how your using it, seems like your using it again after it's been used.. ie m becomes month then you run it again month become monthours because the h in month.

Comment: or it's looping to do the replace, not 100% the implementation of str_replace, but rearranging the order of the letter in the first array can probably fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the manual page for [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace):

> **Caution**
>
> Replacement order gotcha
>
> Because str_replace() replaces left to right, it might replace a previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements. See also the examples in this document.

For example, "m" is replaced with "Month", then the "h" in "Month" is replaced with "Hours", which comes later in the array of replacements.

[strtr()](http://php.net/strtr) doesn't have this issue because it tries all keys of the same length at the same time:

```
$date = strtr($key, array(
    'y' => 'Year',
    'm' => 'Month',
    'd' => 'Days',
    'h' => 'Hours',
    'i' => 'Munites', // [sic]
    's' => 'Seconds',
));
```

Answer (score 9):

### Why doesn't it work?

This is a replacement gotcha which is mentioned in the [documentation for `str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#refsect1-function.str-replace-notes):

> ### Replacement order gotcha
>
> Because `str_replace()` replaces left to right, it might replace a previously inserted value when doing
>   multiple replacements. See also the examples in this document.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
$key = 'm';

$key = str_replace('y', 'Year', $key);
$key = str_replace('m', 'Month', $key);
$key = str_replace('d', 'Days', $key);
$key = str_replace('h', 'Hours', $key);
$key = str_replace('i', 'Munites', $key);
$key = str_replace('s', 'Seconds', $key);

echo $key;
```

As you can see `m` gets replaced with `Month`, and `h` in `Month` gets replaced with `Hours` and the `s` in `Hours` gets replaced with `Seconds`. The problem is that when you're replacing `h` in `Month`, **you're doing it regardless of whether the string `Month` represents what was originally `Month` or what was originally an `m`**. Each `str_replace()` is discarding some information — what the original string was.

This is how you got that result:

```
0) y -> Year
Replacement: none

1) m -> Month
Replacement: m -> Month

2) d -> Days
Replacement: none

3) h -> Hours
Replacement: Month -> MontHours

4) i -> Munites
Replacement: none

5) s -> Seconds
Replacement: MontHours -> MontHourSeconds
```

### The solution

The solution would be to use [`strtr()`](http://php.net/strtr) because **it won't change already replaced characters.**

```
$key = 'm';
$search = array('y', 'm', 'd', 'h', 'i', 's');
$replace = array('Year', 'Month', 'Days', 'Hours', 'Munites', 'Seconds');

$replacePairs = array_combine($search, $replace);
echo strtr($key, $replacePairs); // => Month
```

Answer (score -1):

A simpler fix is to change the search order:

```
array('Year', 'Seconds', 'Hours', 'Month', 'Days', 'Minutes')
```

`str_replace` and `preg_replace` will both search for each search item one at a time. Any multi-value will need to make sure the order doesn't change a previous replace item.

Comment: Doesn't work. Any "s" in the input gets replaced by "SeconDayss".