# Is preg_replace supposed to be iterative when using arrays? Might be a bug

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string that represents a day of the week "U", "M", "T", etc". I'm trying to use preg_replace to replace the letter with the actual day name, like Sunday, Monday, etc.

However, it appears to be applying the array of replacements in an iterative fashion, which isn't what the [documentation](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) appears to specify. Any ideas?

```
$input = "U";
$nice_day_name = preg_replace(['/U/','/M/','/T/','/W/','/R/','/F/','/S/'],
   ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'],
   $input);

// Outputs "Satun", should be "Sun"
```

Comment: Why do you need `preg_replace()` for this at all?  You are just searching for known strings so `str_replace()` should work just fine. Or if you always have a single character input, why not specify an associative array to map the replacements?

Comment: Well, an obvious workaround is to prevent replacing the parts of text that's already replaced - by changing `/T/` for `/T(?!ue|hu)/`, for example. As for the order of processing - well, what else would you expect, without creating potential conflicts?

Comment: *If subject is an array, then the search and replace is performed on every entry of subject*

Comment: @MikeBrant: Nope, [`str_replace()` wouldn't work either](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22575151/1438393).

Comment: @raina77ow Negative lookaheads are anything but obvious :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is better accomplished using [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr):

```
$replacements = [
    "U"=>"Sun",
    "M"=>"Mon",
    "T"=>"Tue",
    "W"=>"Wed",
    "R"=>"Thu",
    "F"=>"Fri",
    "S"=>"Sat"
];
$nice_day_name = strtr($input,$replacements);
```

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](http://php.net/preg-replace) seems to be ambiguous. Here's what it says on the subject:

> If both `pattern` and `replacement` parameters are arrays, each `pattern` will be replaced by the `replacement` counterpart.

It looks like you're reading this as "the *original* string will be checked for each pattern in the array, and the replacement will be made". I can see how one would read it that way. What it seems to be doing instead is checking each pattern against the string, **including any replacements already made**.

So it's doing this:

1. Check the first pattern, `/U/`, find a match, make the replacement --> `Sun`
2. Check a bunch more, find no match
3. Check the last one, `/S/`, find a match (the first character), make the replacement --> `Satun`

To fix this, you can include the start/end character in each pattern:

```
['/^U$/','/^M$/','/^T$/','/^W$/','/^R$/','/^F$/','/^S$/']
```

This will result in a match *only if* the string is one character long.

Comment: "Quote" is a more fitting Markdown to use than "Code" for quoting the docs ;) Edited that for you.

Comment: Hmm... -touches up the Markdown a little more- There!

Answer (score 2):

Don't make the problem harder than it should be:

```
$day_names = array_combine(
    ['U','M','T','W','R','F','S'],
    ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat']
);

$nice_day_name = $day_names[$input];
```

[`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) has the same issue, and I cover this in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575151/1438393) to a different question.

[**Live demo**](https://eval.in/129779)

Comment: ... That works too XD I didn't pay attention to the input being just a single character. +1

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$string = 'U';
$trans = array("U" => "Sun", "M" => "Mon", "T" => "Tue", "W" => "Wed", "R" => "Thu",
 "F" => "Fri", "S" => "Sat");
$result = strtr($string,$trans);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Just a note: this was already suggested by Niet, [in his answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22768816/1438393).

Comment: Oh yes actually it was not available when I started typing and then I tested and posted which took a little time..